# ¿Como usar Volley en vez de HttpUrlConnection para una clase de conexión a Web?

Tags: java, android, android-volley

Tengo la siguiente clase de Android con la cual manejo peticiones POST a una API REST de Laravel, esta está basada en `HttpUrlConnection`:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.net.DhcpInfo;
import android.net.wifi.WifiManager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLEncoder;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class Net {

    private HttpURLConnection urlConnection;

    public String requestString(String url, Map<String, String> parameters) {
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        try {
            URL finalurl = new URL(url);

            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) finalurl.openConnection();
            urlConnection.setReadTimeout(10000);
            urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(15000);
            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            urlConnection.setDoInput(true);

            if (parameters != null) {
                urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
                writeOutput(urlConnection, (HashMap<String, String>) parameters);
            }


            writeInput(urlConnection, result);

            urlConnection.disconnect();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error" + e);
        }

        Log.i("httpResponse", result.toString());

        return result.toString();
    }

    private void writeOutput(HttpURLConnection conn, HashMap<String, String> postDataParams) throws IOException {
        OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
                new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
        writer.write(getPostDataString(postDataParams));

        writer.flush();
        writer.close();
        os.close();
    }

    private void writeInput(HttpURLConnection conn, StringBuilder strb) throws IOException {
        InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(conn.getInputStream());
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));

        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            strb.append(line);
        }
    }

    private String getPostDataString(HashMap<String, String> params) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        boolean first = true;
        for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : params.entrySet()) {
            if (first)
                first = false;
            else
                result.append("&");

            result.append(URLEncoder.encode(entry.getKey(), "UTF-8"));
            result.append("=");
            result.append(URLEncoder.encode(entry.getValue(), "UTF-8"));
        }

        return result.toString();
    }

    public static void logNetInformation(Context c) {
        WifiManager wifii;
        DhcpInfo d;
        String s_dns1;
        String s_dns2;
        String s_gateway;
        String s_ipAddress;
        String s_leaseDuration;
        String s_netmask;
        String s_serverAddress;
        TextView info;

        wifii = (WifiManager) c.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
        d = wifii.getDhcpInfo();

        s_dns1 = "DNS 1: " + String.valueOf(d.dns1);
        s_dns2 = "DNS 2: " + String.valueOf(d.dns2);
        s_gateway = "Default Gateway: " + String.valueOf(d.gateway);
        s_ipAddress = "IP Address: " + String.valueOf(d.ipAddress);
        s_leaseDuration = "Lease Time: " + String.valueOf(d.leaseDuration);
        s_netmask = "Subnet Mask: " + String.valueOf(d.netmask);
        s_serverAddress = "Server IP: " + String.valueOf(d.serverAddress);

        Log.i("Network Info", s_dns1 + "\n" + s_dns2 + "\n" + s_gateway + "\n" + s_ipAddress + "\n" + s_leaseDuration + "\n" + s_netmask + "\n" + s_serverAddress);
    }

    static public String intToIp(int addr) {
        return ((addr & 0xFF) + "." +
                ((addr >>>= 8) & 0xFF) + "." +
                ((addr >>>= 8) & 0xFF) + "." +
                ((addr >>>= 8) & 0xFF));
    }
}
```

Pero recientemente escuche de [Volley](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html) y me preguntaba cuales eran las diferencias, mas específicamente es ¿Debo usar Volley en vez de `HttpUrlConnection` para manejar peticiones Http, por que? También me gustaría saber como se implementa exactamente la misma funcionalidad que provee el código de arriba pero en Volley.

Gracias.

Comment: Yo te recomiendo para las imagenes Glide que es mjy facil de implementar y sistema de cache etc.. para peticiones url HttpOk y si es para consumir servicio web Retrofit, yo volley lo use una sola vez y no me gusta su estructura de uso.

Answer (score 1):

## Volley NO está en desuso

En una de las respuestas se afirma lo siguiente:

> Cabe destacar que volley esta en desuso por lo que tengo entendido y
>   ahora se usa HttpUrlConnection

Creo que cuando afirmemos cosas de este tipo sería mejor documentar la afirmación. Volley **no está en desuso, todo lo contrario, es soportada, documentada y recomendada por Google para hacer peticiones sobre todo si no son muy pesadas**.

### Ventajas de Volley

Según Google, Volley tiene una serie de ventajas nada despreciables, entre ellas:

- Procesamiento concurrente de peticiones múltiples.
- Priorización de las peticiones, lo que permite definir la
  preponderancia de cada petición.
- Cancelación de peticiones, evitando la presentación de resultados no
  deseados en el hilo principal.
- Gestión automática de trabajos en segundo plano, dejando de lado la
  implementación manual de un framework de hilos.
- Implementación de caché en disco y memoria.
- Capacidad de personalización de las peticiones.
- Provee información detallada del estado y flujo de trabajo de las
  peticiones en la consola de depuración.

### Evitar usar Volley en descargas de datos pesados

Aunque Volley posee ventajas enormes para el procesamiento de peticiones, no significa que se debe usar en cada petición que hagamos. Esta librería tiene limitaciones con la descarga de información demasiada extensa, ya que su operación se basa en salvaguardas en caché, lo que haría lento el proceso con datos voluminosos.

### Ejemplo de código

Apreciaremos la sencillez y claridad del uso de Volley:

Para tareas como obtener un json desde un servicio web Volley ofrece posibilidades inmensas con pocas líneas de código.

Aquí un ejemplo de la [página de Google](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/request.html) para una petición JSON:

```
TextView mTxtDisplay;
ImageView mImageView;
mTxtDisplay = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtDisplay);
String url = "http://my-json-feed";

JsonObjectRequest jsObjRequest = new JsonObjectRequest
        (Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

    @Override
    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
        mTxtDisplay.setText("Response: " + response.toString());
    }
}, new Response.ErrorListener() {

    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
});

// Access the RequestQueue through your singleton class.
MySingleton.getInstance(this).addToRequestQueue(jsObjRequest);
```

### Combinación con otras librerías

Aparte de lo ya dicho, Volley abre un amplio abanico de posibilidades cuando la combinamos con otras librerías, como GSON, para un manejo totalmente orientado a objetos de nuestras respuestas JSON obtenidas desde el servicio web.

### Patrón singleton para  evitar el uso de colas de conexión

Si nuestra aplicación hace uso constante de internet o necesita realizar peticiones a lo largo de todas sus actividades y componentes. Esta situación haría que muchos programadores declararan colas de peticiones por todos lados o incluso pasar como parámetro la cola entre clases, lo cual llega  a ser repetitivo, poco eficiente y confuso.

Para desmontar este complejo enfoque, con Volley Google ofrece la posibilidad y recomienda crear un Patrón Singleton que encapsule las funcionalidades necesarias de Volley. Este patrón se caracteriza por limitar el alcance de la clase a un solo objeto, es decir, solo puede existir un solo objeto controlador que represente la existencia de la clase, restringiendo la instanciación de nuevos elementos.

Con esta solución, el singleton será omnipresente en todo el proyecto Android y se podrán usar las funcionalidades en cualquier lugar. Básicamente esta clase debe contener como atributo la cola de peticiones y el contexto de la aplicación (ojo, no el contexto de la actividad, ya que es necesario establecer independencia de la interfaz, por si en algún momento existe un cambio de configuración, como la rotación de pantalla).

Si nuestra aplicación hace conexiones puntuales a la red no sería necesario implementar dicho patrón.

Fuentes:

- [Guía de Volley en Google (en inglés)](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html)
- [Un excelente tutorial de Volley en español](http://www.hermosaprogramacion.com/2015/02/android-volley-peticiones-http/)

Comment: Pero al rotar el dispositivo se pierde la referencia de la actividad y volley puedes estar descargando en segundo plano data que no es tan facil recuperar no? y rendimiento aqui hay un benchmark http://instructure.github.io/blog/2013/12/09/volley-vs-retrofit/

Comment: @Webserveis Interesante lo que dices. ¿Sabes si hay alguna manera de evitar eso usando Volley? Aunque no sé si es mi teléfono o que Android ha cambiado en eso, porque de hecho en mi dispositivo ocurría que, habiendo tomado contenido de un servidor remoto, **hace tiempo cargaba de nuevo todos los datos** al girar la pantalla, pero desde hace más o menos un mes ya no lo hace, sino que cambia la pantalla y gira el contenido. Lo sé porque en la parte que carga el contenido desde la red tengo un Dialog para indicar que _espere_ y ahora ese Dialog no sale al girar la pantalla.

Answer (score 0):

prueba con

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

private static final String REGISTER_URL = "http://estoesunserver.com/UserRegistration/volleyRegister.php";

public static final String KEY_USERNAME = "username";
public static final String KEY_PASSWORD = "password";
public static final String KEY_EMAIL = "email";


private EditText editTextUsername;
private EditText editTextEmail;
private EditText editTextPassword;

private Button buttonRegister;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    editTextUsername = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextUsername);
    editTextPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextPassword);
    editTextEmail= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextEmail);

    buttonRegister = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonRegister);

    buttonRegister.setOnClickListener(this);
}

private void registerUser(){
    final String username = editTextUsername.getText().toString().trim();
    final String password = editTextPassword.getText().toString().trim();
    final String email = editTextEmail.getText().toString().trim();

    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, REGISTER_URL,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,response,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,error.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }){
        @Override
        protected Map<String,String> getParams(){
            Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put(KEY_USERNAME,username);
            params.put(KEY_PASSWORD,password);
            params.put(KEY_EMAIL, email);
            return params;
        }

    };

    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if(v == buttonRegister){
        registerUser();
    }
}
```

}

Cabe destacar que `volley` esta en desuso por lo que tengo entendido y ahora se usa `HttpUrlConnection` saludos

Comment: Fijece que es un "String Request", en este caso el servidor esta esperando un string, hay otros casos en los que el request es del tipo JSON

Answer (score 0):

Te lo dejo el Volley que uso, es cortito!

```
 public void onClick(View v) {

    RequestQueue cola = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

    String url = "TU URL";

    final StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest
(Request.Method.POST, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {

                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {

                //Te devuelve el parametro    response 
                // En este se encuentra todo lo que te devuelve

                TextView.setText(response);

            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

            System.out.println("ERROR RESPONSE");
        }
    });
    cola.add(stringRequest);}
```