# ¿Como verificar respuesta del servidor?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-volley

estoy desarrollando una app android, el servidor me responde creando un json desde php, pero ha momento se demora en la generación del texto y hasta eso el AsycnAsk ya me recibe como error un null.

Como puedo hacer para controlar eso?

Esta es la función.

```
private class ProductosLoadTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Cursor> {
    @Override
    protected Cursor doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        try{
            mDbHelper.BorrarProductos();             
            JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayReq = new JsonArrayRequest(url_productos,
                    new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {                             
                            try
                            {
                                txt_tot_pro.setText("Espere... procesando");
                                JSONObject obj=null;                                                                        
                                for (int a=0; a<response.length();a++) {                                        
                                    obj = response.getJSONObject(a);                                      
                                    save_producto=new producto(
                                            obj.getString("IMA_ARTICULO"),
                                            obj.getString("IMA_DESCRIPCION"),
                                            obj.getString("IMA_LINEA"),
                                            obj.getString("IMA_IMPUESTO"),
                                            obj.getString("IMA_COSTO_PROMEDIO"),
                                            obj.getString("IMA_PRECIO1"),
                                            obj.getString("IMA_PRECIO2"),
                                            obj.getString("IMA_PRECIO3"),
                                            obj.getString("IMA_PRECIO4"),
                                            obj.getString("IMA_PRECIO5"),
                                            obj.getString("IMA_PRECIO6"),
                                            obj.getString("IMA_PRECIO7"),
                                            obj.getString("IMA_PRECIO8"),
                                            obj.getString("IMA_PRECIO9"),
                                            obj.getString("IMA_PRECIO10"),
                                            obj.getString("IMA_SUBLINEA"),
                                            obj.getString("EXISTENCIA"),
                                            obj.getString("PACK"),"1","cb");
                                    mDbHelper.nuevoProducto(save_producto);
                                }
                                txt_tot_pro.setText("Listo, sincronizacion completa");
                                SyncReceive(posSyncRe);
                            }catch (JSONException e){
                                Log.e(TAG, "parseJsonProductos ",e );
                            }
                        }
                    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    VolleyLog.d(TAG, "ErrorProductos: " + error.getMessage());
                    Log.i(TAG, "onErrorResponseProductos: "+error.getMessage());
                }
            });
            Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity()).add(jsonArrayReq);
        }catch (Exception error){
            Log.i(TAG, "parseJsonProductos error: " + error.toString());
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        txt_tot_pro.setText("Espere... Conectando");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Cursor cursor) {
        super.onPostExecute(cursor);
        txt_tot_pro.setText("Sincronizado(s)  producto(s)");
    }
}
```

Comment: Puedes pedirle a `Volley` que alargue un poco más el tiempo de espera. Ahora no tengo el código a mano. Pero ten en cuenta que `Volley` no es recomendable para peticiones al servidor que supongan grandes cantidades de datos, por ejemplo, imágenes pesadas a archivos multimedia. Si son cuestiones de bases de datos, ten en cuenta optimizar también la BD y la forma de consultarla. Para ver si no es problema del servidor, prueba una consulta no desde la App, sino desde el navegador... si tarde demasiado, debes optimizar del lado del servidor. [Ver esto](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/50336/29967)

Comment: Me parece que el problema esta mas en el servidor que en android. Que datos es que retornas desde el servidor y cual es el peso?

Comment: @Einer el paso del archigo plano es de 550KB, no se pero a ratos me devuelve NULL y da error.